# Can I use two child selector ".foo>a.bar>a", which is similar to ".foo.bar"?

Tags: css, menu, css-selectors, parent-child, css-specificity

I was making a menu list and would like to have a color change on the tab of current active page.

```css
.menu>li>a {color: red;}
.menu>li>a.active>a {color: blue;}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="active"><a href="">active page</a></li>
  <li><a href="">another page</a></li>
  <li><a href="">other page</a></li>
</ul>
```

([JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/xaxubi/14/edit?html,css,output))

In the code above, I want active page tab to be blue. However, I can't use `.menu>li>a.active>a` to change the color.

I remember that I can select classes like `.foo.bar` for a `.foo` under a specific condition `.bar`. However, like example above, it seems that I can't do it if there's child element, like `.foo>a.bar>a`.

Is this correct? Also, is there a better strategy for this kind of condition?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Can you explain further?

Comment: Sure! Let me edit again.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this?
.menu>li.active>a { color: red } // Active menu item
.menu>li>a { color: blue} // Non-active menu item.
I'm also confused by your question

Comment: @tenderloin Well, the opposite one. I want the blue active menu item, red for else (non-active).

Comment: Cool, so try switching them around like this: .menu>li.active>a { color: blue; } // Active menu item .menu>li>a { color: red; } // Non-active menu item. Is that what you're after?

Comment: Oops! You remind me of this thing in my code... I shouldn't use this `...a.active...`, which means <a class="active">. This is not what I want.

Comment: @tenderloin I was hoping that I can make a general color `.menu>li>a`, and a color change under a specific condition `(.menu>li>a)(.active>a)` . (Of course, I can't use parentheses.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> .menu>li>a {color: red;} .menu>li>a.active>a {color: blue;}

**Your above CSS code is wrong**, that's why it's not working.
You are having `class="active"` on `<li>` element, so you should use this css -

```
.menu>li>a {color: red;}
.menu>li.active>a {color: blue;}
```

Also `.foo.bar` css selector will work on elements having both the class, for example -

```css
.foo.bar {
  color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo bar">Multiple Class Element</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
.menu li.active a{
  color: blue;
}

.menu li a{
  color: red;
}
```